# php5ts.dll error on Windows 2008R2 server with XAMPP / Magento e-Commerce platform

Tags: php, magento, windows-server-2008

This has been driving me nuts. Magento won't offer support on a Windows background and I don't have the XAMPP knowledge.

I am running XAMPP Win32 1.7.4 VC6 on a Windows 2008R2 (64bit) server with the Magento Professional ver 1.10.0.1.

I have had the site running now for over 3 months with no problems. Then completely out of the blue Apache started crashing every 5-10 seconds - with an error in the php5ts.dll module causing a memory exception in the Windows shell. The service is terminated and then immediately restarted by Windows (as an automatic restart service).

Here is the output from the Event Viewer:

Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.2.17.0, time stamp: 0x4cbbe9e8
Faulting module name: php5ts.dll, version: 5.3.5.0, time stamp: 0x4d26013e
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x00172a76
Faulting process id: 0x18a04
Faulting application start time: 0x01cc83d88b9af0a8
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Administrator\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Users\Administrator\xampp\php\php5ts.dll
Report Id: 17d7c3eb-efcd-11e0-b478-002590507612

I have tried everything I have found on the internet - replacing DLL, EXE, using dependency walker to look at missing libraries and moving files from one folder to another and I'm confused and stuck !

Has anyone else had this issue with XAMPP on 2008 and found a resolution ?

Comment: if you observe magento system requirements then you notice that windows is not a supported platform

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [article](http://benjisimon.blogspot.com/2009/02/gotcha-of-day-apache-and-php-crashing.html). Seems like magento got infinite recursion somewhere. Try disable 3rd party modules (if you have any). If it doesn't help - try change PHP version and/or update magento to 1.11 version.